# Speed up loading large GeoJSON layers to Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, mapping, large-datasets, progress

I have some GeoJSON data layers which I fetch their features from phpMyAdmin to display on a Leaflet map.

But loading the features takes almost 10 seconds to be loaded.

Have you any solution to speed up the loading process?

My data layer has a multipolygon type which covered data for boundary of Turkey provinces. accordingly each item has a long vertex info. i load them as text (1000000) and then convert by `ST_GeomFromText(WKT,26913)` to geometry.

I use the folowing code to add that to map:

```
       var Layer1 = L.layerGroup();
        
        // Fetch the GeoJSON data from the PHP file
        fetch('Layer1 .php')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                L.geoJSON(data, {
                    style: function (feature) {
                        return {
                            stroke: true,
                            color: '#980043',
                            weight: 2,
                            fillOpacity: 0.3                            
                         };
                    },
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    var popupContent = "<b> some text" ;
                    
                    layer.bindTooltip(popupContent, { sticky: true });
                }
                }).addTo(Layer1); 
            });
        Layer1 .addTo(map);
```

Additionally, can I add a progress bar that display data loading process of layers to map?

Comment: Simplest solution would be to zip GeoJSON data on the server side and unzip it on the client side.

Comment: This needs some perf measuremets: the bottleneck might be either in the client (JS) or the webserver (PHP). How much time does the browser take to load, and how much to process?

Comment: Simplify? And store a binary format rather than geojson

Comment: Maybe changing your overall concept and switching to WMS / WFS / Vector Tiles

Comment: could you give some more detail on this methods? where can i found related documantation or any examples?

Comment: Zipping on the server side: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php. Unzipping on the client side: https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/